# Yii: How to refresh or unset or reset a model?

Tags: php, yii

I need to refresh, reset or unset a model;

Normally, by using a `for` operation, the `public static $k` value should change, and id does change, but the `tableName` model method is called only once;

the value of `tablename` will always be `1`, because that is the fisrt value of `$i`;

```
for($i=1;$i<=100;$i++){
VillageBuildingKXSlaveM::$server_id = 1;
VillageBuildingKXSlaveM::$k = $i;
VillageBuildingKXSlaveM::model()->findAllByAttributes(array());
}

<?php

class VillageBuildingKXSlaveM extends VillageBuildingKXM {

    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public static $server_id;
    public static $slave_db;
    public static $k;

    public function getDbConnection() {
        self::$slave_db = Yii::app()->dbx;
        if (self::$slave_db instanceof CDbConnection) {
            self::$slave_db->active = false;
            $config = require(Yii::app()->getBasePath() . '/config/main.php');
            $connectionString = $config['components']['dbx']['connectionString'];
            self::$slave_db->connectionString = sprintf($connectionString, self::$server_id);
            self::$slave_db->setActive(true);
            return self::$slave_db;
        } else
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii', 'Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }

    public function tableName() {
        return 'village_building_k' . self::$k;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
VillageBuildingKXSlaveM::model()->unsetAttributes();
```

to unset the attributes in a model
Or you can also pass the attributes name as arguments in the method like

```
VillageBuildingKXSlaveM::model()->unsetAttributes($attributes);
```

Comment: It will work as it does always for me. It depends on where you are using it. try to echo the attribute you are unsetting after it and see if you get its value or null

Answer (score -1):

You can call

```
VillageBuildingKXSlaveM::model()->tableName();
```